# Co-Existience of two different NodeJS for same project

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I am quite new to NodeJS and am planning to upgrade NodeJS version for my current project. The most recent NodeJS LTS is installed using NVM.

I need to keep switching between the current LTS that i am using and the new LTS that has been installed. I understand that i can do 'NVM use' for this purpose. npm-shrinkwrap.json is being used to lock down the npm package dependencies.

I am planning to follow the below approach both in my dev machine and build machine;
Is it okay? If not, please suggest a best approach.

- nvm use latest_LTS

  Update the package.json to pick the version which is supported by
  latest_LTS

  npm install

  generate testing_build

Whenever i need to generate a build for current release (with the previous LTS NodeJS)

- nvm use currently_used_LTS

  clear the node modules

  npm install (Release npm-shrinkwrap.json)

  generate release_build

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In theory that should work.

However have you considered the option of just doing a point release for the current release_build that does nothing except version-bump node?

You may find (after re-running your tests) that the latest version of node is backwards compatable with release_build (or only requires minor fixes), and you can simplify your life by porting everything to the latest node version, rather than constantly switching

Comment: Thanks @James McGuigan; I will not be able to make a release with just version-bump node as few node packages being used are deprecated and i will have to update them to use the recent NodeJS LTS.